# Sub-domain in local network (windows server 2012) to open apache site (port 8085)

Tags: apache, iis, dns, windows-server-2012

I have windows server 2012 installed on machine in local network (port 80) and I have Apache installed on the same machine (port 8085).

I want to setup sub-domain or virtual domain like my-domain.com  to open an application from Apache  (inside the network). 
I've tried to setup new website via IIS with port 8085 but I got this error message

```
the process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process
```

Thank you in advance.

Comment: It may be because the process id (PID) of apache sever is conflicting.? May be change the `.pid` file for the process.

Comment: You stated apache was already bound to port 8085, so you cannot start IIS attached to that port as well. Your options are create a sub-interface with a different address to attach IIS on port 8085 to, or use a different port.